# How to fix Unable to autoload constant Api::Common::OrganizationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi Rails hackers and guru!

I have a stable autoloading development-only problem:

> Unable to autoload constant Api::Common::OrganizationController, expected /home/user/Work/project/app/controllers/api/common/organization_controller.rb to define it

Error appears on first xhr request on chrome. 
If I repeat request, error dissapear.

File `/home/user/Work/project/app/controllers/api/common/organization_controller.rb` exists:

```
module Api
  module Common
    class OrganizationController < ::Api::BaseController
      def show
```

Comment: Hate to state the obvious but check for typos - that setup looks correct

Comment: Please, provide your `controllers` directory content

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev $ ls app/controllers/
api  application_controller.rb  attachments_controller.rb  concerns  errors_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

I would make a suggestion that you have to add these files to your directories:
Under `.../app/controllers` create file `api.rb` with content:

```rb
module Api; end
```

Under `.../app/controllers/api/` create file `common.rb` with content:

```rb
module Common; end
```

it should help